# Action does not trigger reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm trying to implement search, and I did the action for input which works every time when I enter text to search input, but the reducer does not trigger and I can't understand why, and the strangest thing, that another actions and reducers work as it should, and only one doesn't.

search component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import './search.css';


import axios from 'axios'
import {getPlayList,setSearchValue} from "./actions";
import {connect} from "react-redux";



class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    query: '',
    results: []
  };

  getInfo = () => {
   this.props.getPlayList(this.state.query);
   console.log(this.props.search.searchPlayList);
  };

  handleInputChange = () => {
    /*this.setState({
      query: this.search.value
    }, () => {
      if (this.state.query && this.state.query.length > 1) {
          this.getInfo();

      }

    });*/
    setSearchValue(this.search.value);
    console.log(this.props.search.searchValue);

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          placeholder="Search for..."
          ref={input => this.search = input}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
      </form>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = store => {
  return {
    search: store.search
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getPlayList,setSearchValue})(Search);
```

Action methods:

```
export const getPlayList = (queryParam) => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({type: FETCH_PLAYLIST_REQUEST});
    axios.get(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.deezer.com/search/track?q=${queryParam}`).then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_PLAYLIST_SUCCESS,
        payload: {
          playlist: response.data.data,
          currentTrack: response.data.data[0]
        }
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_PLAYLIST_FAILURE,
        payload: err,
      });
    })
  }
};

export const setSearchValue = (value) => {
  console.log('setSearchValue',value);
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({
      type: FETCH_SEARCH_VALUE,
      payload: value,
    });
  }
}
```

Reducer

```
import {
  FETCH_PLAYLIST_FAILURE,
  FETCH_PLAYLIST_REQUEST,
  FETCH_PLAYLIST_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_SEARCH_VALUE
} from "../actions/types";


const initialState = {
  searchPlayList:null,
  currentTrack:null,
  searchValue:null,
  index: 0,
  isLoading: false,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_PLAYLIST_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true
      };
    case FETCH_PLAYLIST_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        searchPlayList: action.payload.playlist,
        errors: null,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    case FETCH_PLAYLIST_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        errors: action.payload
      };
    case FETCH_SEARCH_VALUE:
      console.log('action.payload',action.payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        searchValue: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

and how it works 
[image]

Comment: Where do you hook up your reducer with `combineReducers` ?

Comment: @HåkenLid in root reducer  
`import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import playlist from './playlist';
import player from './player';
import search from './search'

export default combineReducers({
  playlist,
  player,
  search
})`

Answer (score 3):

You have to change this line:

```
setSearchValue(this.search.value);
```

To this:

```
this.props.setSearchValue(this.search.value);
```

The `setSearchValue` in props will dispatch the action to the store. Just calling `setSearchValue` by itself doesn't do anything, since it has not been connected to redux.